# Html Frames and Body

Tags: html, frames, frameset

we are using Html frames for our website. Now we need to add some widget on right side and we dont want to make a frame for it too.
Is there any option that this widget can be displayed on the right side, above the frame without affecting the frames?
Or even if i make a frame for widget, is it possible to resize the frame when it is expanded. Because when the content of frame is expanded, half of the content is not visible.

Comment: This is very vague - all this depends on actual coding in place - url / code please

Comment: Frames are deprecated and using them is highly discouraged, as modern browsers may drop support for them (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame). I'd venture a guess that what you're trying to accomplish would actually be easier using divs instead of frames anyway. :)

Answer (score -1):

Look at z-indexing here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

And think about absolute positioning. Here is another link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

You could also work with some javascript to hide the widget off of the screen until it is called on. Sounds like a design eye and some research are needed, but there are some good solutions out there for what you require.